# Getting outofbounds error, don't know what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I don't understand what am I doing wrong or how do I get the `OutOfBounds` exception

My output is

> Your current elements are: `{cat dog gerbil }`
>   What's the new pet that you got?

My error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4        
at PetFunRunner.insertElement(PetFunRunner.java:67)       
at PetFunRunner.main(PetFunRunner.java:35)
```

My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] originalPets = {"cat", "dog", "gerbil"};
    printArray(originalPets);

    // PART A
    System.out.println("What's the new pet that you got?");
    String pet = in.nextLine();
    String[] updatedPets = insertElement(originalPets, pet);
    printArray(updatedPets);
}
public static String[] insertElement(String[] origArray, String stringToInsert)
{
    String[] newPets = new String[origArray.length + 1];
    int s = newPets.length;
    newPets[s] = stringToInsert;
    return newPets;
}
```

Comment: Insert new string at `length-1`, Index are 0 based in array.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  Firstly, in `insertElement`, you're not copying the original array into the new one.  Secondly, you're inserting the new element past the end of the array.  The array goes from `0` to `s-1`, but you're trying to insert at index `s`, which gives your exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `insertElement` with an array with 3 elements, your array `newPets` will have a `length` of 4. These elements are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]`.

Then you try to access the element with the index equal to its length, which is `[4]`. There is no such element, so you get an out-of-bounds exception.